# defalut " excluded ** " in myeclipse 10 ,and Why?

Tags: maven, myeclipse

I have a maven project in myeclipse 10, after I set a directory as the ***resource directory*** (use build->resources->resource->directory element in the pom.xml) ,I want to set it's *excludes* like **/*.txt ,then the trouble is coming: the confiration of this *build path(directory)* be setted show it's exluded like below :  excluded **. why? How can I set it instead of the default by myself.